# Javascript Submit from from pageA to pageB

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, electron

I am trying to write some code where I have the pageA.html and pageB.html

On pageB.html I have a form:

```
<form>
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" value="">
  <br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" value="">
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Both pages are on my localhost.

I need to add some code on pageA.html that with hit the submit button on pageB.html

Is this possible? If yes, How can I do this?

Comment: do you need to redirect from pageA to pageB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, It is not possible by using only html. You have to use any server-side scripting language like PHP or C# etc.

Comment: What about NodeJs? Can node do it?

Comment: Yes, It is possible because nodeJs is a powerful server side scripting language

Comment: Do I create another question asking the same thing? I need to find out how it's done in NodeJs